# Hosting WPF Xbap application in Azure fails

Tags: wpf, azure, xbap

As given in this -> [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2425647) , i am trying to host a WPF Xbap application in a cloud service application but am getting the below error.

[image]

ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* An exception occurred while downloading the application. Following failure messages were detected:
+ Downloading http:// localhost:62773/Newtonsoft.Json.dll.deploy did not succeed.
+ The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Please advice.

Comment: As the error indicates, the application tries to download `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` from `localhost` instead of your web server. My guess is that somewhere the links are not updating properly in your application deployment package.

Comment: Hi, Have you tried hosting any XBAP application in azure>?

Comment: No I haven't. I just looked at the error and made the comment.

Comment: Oh ok..cool. please let me know if any one ur pals tried it out.